# How to add to a list inside a loop in python?

Tags: python, loops

I'm trying to assign data from an excel file (data2) to a variable and create a list of this data of an amount which has previously been specified (targets).

```
follow=data2[1][2]
for q in range(2,targets):
   follow = follow,data2[q][2]
```

However this returns:

```
(((((((((((((((((('targetdata1','targetdata2','targetdata3',...)
```

Where "(" is increasing for every loop process. My desired output would be:

```
('targetdata1','targetdata2','targetdata3',..)
```

Comment: Your indent is broken and you are not giving us all of the data.  You will get more and better answers if you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.  Especially make sure that the input and expected test data are complete (not pseudo-data), and can be easily cut and and paste into an editor to allow testing proposed solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Comma is used for creating tuples. So

```
follow = follow, data2[q][2]
```

sets `follow` to a tuple whose first element is the old value of `follow` and second element is the item from `data2`. So this keeps nesting it deeper and deeper, by putting one tuple inside another tuple.

You should be using `follow.append()`:

```
follow.append(data2[q][2])
```

You can do the whole thing with a list comprehension:

```
follow = [x[2] for x in data2[1:]]
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do can best be expressed in a list comprehension:

```
follow = [data[i][2] for i in range(i,targets)]
```

And just to make sure: list/tuple indices in python start with 0. You are skipping the first element. i assume this is on purpose, to skip the headers of the table or something.